# Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1) in Fortran

Tags: fortran, series

I'm trying to compute this series

[image: this series]

in Fortran 77.
The point is to be able to get the exact solution for the equation -∆u(x,y) = 0 so i can compare it to the analytical solution with the 2D finite difference but i'm getting this error:

```
68 |       s(k)=s(k)+ (dsin(2.d0*k+1.d0)*(((T-j)/n) +1.d0)*h*PI*
   |      1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

```
c23456
 TP1c
C     variables
      implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
      DIMENSION Xexact(1000) ,A(1000,1000)
      DIMENSION  Xo(1000),R(1000),F(1000), Xapp(1000),C(1000),s(1000)
      DIMENSION temp_r(1000),Y(1000),vec1(1000),vec(1000), T(1000)

      n=3
      m=n*n
      h=1.d0/(n+1)

C     exact solution
      PI=4.d0*datan(1.d0)
      DO i=1,m
         s(i)=0.d0
         T(i)=0.d0
      ENDDO
      DO k=1,m
              T(k)=k
      ENDDO
C      CALL affich_vec(T,m)
      
      DO k=1,100
        DO i=1,n
         DO j=1,n
             DO l=1,m
      s(k)=s(k)+ (sin((2.d0*k+1.d0)*(((T-j)/n) +1.d0)*h*PI)*
     &  sinh((2.d0*k+1.d0)*(T-n*(i-1.d0))*h*PI))/((2.d0*k+1.d0)
     &  *sinh((2.d0*k+1.d0)*PI))
         Xexact(l)=(400.d0/PI)*s(l)
             ENDDO
         ENDDO
        ENDDO
       ENDDO
       CALL affich_vec(Xexact,m)
      end
```

the subroutine to show the vector along with it.

```
C=======================================================================
     SUBROUTINE   affich_vec(X,n)

C     Declaration des variables
     implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
     DIMENSION  X(1000)

C     Affichage du vecteur :
     write(*,*) 'Vecteur  :'
     DO i=1,n
       write(*,*)X(i)
     ENDDO

     return
     end
C=======================================================================
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Be aware it is really bad to use  `implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)`. You should always use `implicit none`. It is even worse when you are asking for help from other people. Always use `implicit none` when you are asking for help. Also be aware that we cannot try to compile your code, it is incomplete. See [mcve], we normally need a full piece of code.

Comment: What is `T-j` supposed to mean? One is an array and one is an index. You can do that in Fortran 90, but you probably do not. The same for `-n*(i-1.d0)`.

Comment: T is an array for me. if T = [1,2,3,4] i, T - j give you [1 - j,2-j,3-j,4-j] so if j = 1 for example, it gives you [0,1,2,3]

Comment: my bad  i added half of the code + the subroutine to show the vector. I'm not allowed to use Fortran 90 for this one.

Comment: If you are using array syntax it certainly isn't Fortran77 - it is at least Fortran 90 or later

Comment: Be aware that such array operations are not allowed in Fortran 77. But more importantly, what do you hope to achieve with the `[1 - j,2-j,3-j,4-j]` array when you are assigning the result to `s(k)` which is scalar? It just does not make sense.

Comment: @IanBush i declared it as T(1000)

Comment: @VladimirF my hope was to get the value of the exact the solution in every point of the grid T(x_i,y_j) for  n = 3, 1<=i<=3; 1<=j<=3  
Yeah, you're right, i'm going to look into it again.

Comment: Please keep the original title, it tells much better what kind of problem you have. Better for others with the same problem. If you want to ask something else with an updated code, you can open a new question.